# Postgres array lookup in WHERE clause

Tags: arrays, postgresql, where-clause

I have a query:

```
SELECT bar, (SELECT name FROM names WHERE value = bar) as name
FROM foobar WHERE foo = 1 and bar = ANY (1,2,3)
```

My problem is, when there is no row containing `bar = 3` (or whatever other value is requested) in table `foobar`, no rows are returned for that value of bar.

I'd like my query to return a row of `[bar, NULL]` instead, but can't think up a way to approach this.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Two things should clear up your query: `left outer join` will join as you request. Second, arrays are not really made to be searched through like mini tables. If you do not know the index of the array there is a good chance you are misusing them.

Comment: I think the array is a red herring here.  I believe he wants a row of (bar, NULL) returned, which makes sense in his context.

Comment: Peter, array is just a way to accommodate multiple values of bar without having to generate a lot of 'bar = x or bar = y or...' clauses. I have no control over the bar values, it's my input and it can contain one or more values I have to query against. Hence the array. If there's more streamlined way to do this with SQL, I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: I think your question and my answer would be a better fit over on [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) - if you agree, are you willing to consider self-flagging for migration there?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps something like this approach is what you are after:

testbed:

```
create view names as 
select 1 as value, 'Adam' as name union all select 2, 'Beth';

create view foobar as 
select 1 as foo, 1 as bar union all select 1, 2;
```

original method:

```
select bar, (select name from names where value = bar) as name 
from foobar 
where foo = 1 and bar = any (array[1, 2, 3]);

 bar | name
-----+------
   1 | Adam
   2 | Beth
(2 rows)
```

alternative method:

```
with w as (select unnest(array[1, 2, 3]) as bar)
select bar, (select name from names where value = bar) as name
from w left outer join foobar using(bar);

 bar | name
-----+------
   1 | Adam
   2 | Beth
   3 |
(3 rows)
```

If you are on 8.3 or before, there is no built-in `unnest` function, but you can roll your own (not very efficient) replacement:

```
create or replace function unnest(anyarray) returns setof anyelement as $$
  select $1[i] from generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) i;
$$ language 'sql' immutable;
```

Comment: Jack, that's it. I have already found this wonderful unnest() function and even started to write an answer to my own question but you got there first. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Alexander You are very welcome - I've added an `unnest` function for anyone who is on <8.4 (not you of course as you've already said it works for you)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT bar, name
FROM foobar
INNER JOIN names ON foobar.bar = names.value
WHERE foo = 1 and bar = ANY (1,2,3)
```

Try that query instead.

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but neither INNER JOIN nor LEFT JOIN does the trick. LEFT JOIN returns all rows where bar is defined, and I need to return a row for every requested value of bar, whether it exists in the foobar table or not. This is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  vals.bar, name
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    unnest([1, 2, 3]) AS bar
        ) vals
LEFT JOIN
        foobar
ON      foobar.foo = 1
        AND foobar.bar = vals.bar
LEFT JOIN
        names
ON      names.value = vals.bar
```